# Tikz, foreach, evaluate and \ifodd combination yields "Use of \@next does not match it's definition"

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm trying to run this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw\foreach \s [evaluate=\s as \lowhigh using \s+1] in {1,...,4}{
            \ifodd\lowhigh node (\s) {\s} \fi
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And get

> Use of  @next does not match it's  definition

I'm assuming this because `\lowhigh` is not an integer anymore due to whatever `evaluate` does. Is there a simple way to fix this?
(My actual code is of course more complex, so I'd need something that solves the problem without getting replacing the `evaluate` with something else.

Comment: try `using int(\s+1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this ?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \s [evaluate=\s as \lowhigh using int(\s+1)] in {1,...,4}{
            \ifodd\lowhigh \node at (\s,0) (\s) {\s}; \fi
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw foreach \s [evaluate=\s as \lowhigh using int(\s+1)] in {1,...,4}{
            \ifodd\lowhigh node at (\s,0) (\s) {\s} \fi
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Same screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Great, now I feel stupid :D